# Delphi FMX | E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Tags: delphi, mobile, firemonkey, path, component

Bom dia. Comigo está dando vários erros. veja minha procedure que procura dentro de um TLayout um TPath, através de um loop de 1 a 4 (a procedure começa na linha 814):

```
procedure TFrmPrincipal.path_opacity;
var
  x : integer;
  path : TPath;
begin

  // reset nas configuracções dos 4 icones (tpath)...
  for x := 1 to 4 do
    begin
      path := TPath(FrmPrincipal.FindComponent('lay_path' + x.ToString).FindComponent('Path' + x.ToString))
      // with TPath(FrmPrincipal.FindComponent('lay_path' + x.ToString).FindComponent('Path' + x.ToString)) do
      with path do
      // with TPath(FrmPrincipal.FindComponent('Path' + x.ToString)) do
        begin
          // Margins.bottom := 15;
          // Tanimator.AnimatFloat(path,'width', 40, 0.4, TAnimationType.out,TinterpolationType.elastic);
        end;
    end;
```

Os erros são:

> [dcc32 Error] UnitPrincipal.pas(825): E2089 Invalid typecast
>
> [dcc32 Error] UnitPrincipal.pas(830): E2010 Incompatible types:
> 'TPath' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

alguém pode me ajudar?

gratidão

Comment: Gostaria de agradecer ao Moacyr do grupo do "tele_gram" "Delbi BR" que nos mostrou a solução.
O TPath são usados pelo delphi por 2 classes, componentes ou locais:
► TPath = record; e
► TPath = FMX.Objects

Portanto, o TPath (imagem SVG), não se pude usar pelo FindComponent como apenas TPath, deve ser usado assim em todos os locais que ele é referenciado:
FMX.Objetcts.TPath.

Conforme meu código acima, veja um exemplo correto de uma das linhas:
 path := FMX.Objetcs.TPath(FrmPrincipal.FindComponent('lay_path' + x.ToString).FindComponent('Path' + x.ToString))

gratidão
Paz&GraçadeDeus